# Regarding to the developer determined criteria in play store subscription

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase, android-billing, play-billing-library

We have created a monthly product on the Google Play Store and added an offer with a phase such as a 1-month free trial. Now, we want to make this offer eligible for existing users so that they receive the offer every time. For that purpose, we chose the "developer determined" option. However, when we click on such a plan, it directly displays the amount without the free trial popup.

So, we set the criteria to "developer determined".

We have other subscriptions as well. Suppose a user is subscribed to another plan, and now that plan has expired, and they want to take advantage of the 30-day free trial. In this case, it's showing the base plan amount instead of the 30-day free trial. However, it should display the free trial because we selected the criteria as "developer determined". Do we need to write code from our end to satisfy this logic?